# Is there any other way to write update operation in Angular 8

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular8

Update method is not working in my Angular 8 project.Can I know the appropriate way to do it.

```
update(data) {
  return this.afs
   .collection("Halls")
   .doc(data.payload.doc.id
   .set({ completed: true }, { merge: true });
  }
```

I need to update data in firestore named 'Halls' which i have already inserted to the database. Following code shows html code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="update(data)">Update</button>
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Nothing happens. update is not working though I clicked the button.